# Inconveniente al cambiar strings modificando functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, str-replace

Quiero cambiar strings modificando el archivo functions.php del child theme, el problema es que cambia los strings indicados ("Proyectos" y "Entradas") pero por algún motivo no cambia uno de los principales ("Entradas"), ¿alguien sabe que puede estar pasando?.
El código que aplico es el siguiente:

```
add_filter(  'gettext',  'wps_translate_words_array'  );
add_filter(  'ngettext',  'wps_translate_words_array'  );
function wps_translate_words_array( $translated ) {
 
     $words = array(
            'Entradas' => 'Novedades',
            'Proyectos' => 'Servicios',
            );
 
     $translated = str_ireplace(array_keys($words),  $words,  $translated );
     return $translated;
}
```

[image: Resultado de la ejecución del código]

Comment: No se si sea eso, pero la funcion str_irepalce no la conozco, creo que deberia ser str_replace. Aqui te dejo la documentacion de esa funcion: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php

Comment: @MateoGuio la función str_ireplace si existe: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-ireplace.php

Comment: Claro, es similar, la diferencia es que `str_replace` es case sensitive, `str_ireplace` no.

Comment: ¿Solo quieres cambiar las etiquetas en el menú? Entonces deberías hacer algo como lo que sugieren en [este enlace](https://gist.github.com/raaar/9206302). Si quieres que se cambie en todo el sitio, lo mejor es editar el archivo de idioma y así no tienes que modificar código.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Triby funcionó perfecto, solo quería cambiar las etiquetas.